# Confusion on clock synchronization

Tags: special-relativity

I am reading through Polonyi's Classical Field Theory [notes](http://www.iphc.cnrs.fr/IMG/pdf/radiation.pdf). It begins with a discussion of special relativity, and near the bottom of page 3, it introduces a procedure for synchronizing clocks. I've reproduced the paragraph below.

> Let us suppose that we can introduce a coordinate system by means of meter rods that characterize points in space and all are in rest. Then we place a clock at each space point which will be synchronized in the following manner. We pick the clock at one point, $x = 0$ in Fig. 1, as a reference, its finger being used to construct the flow of time at $x=0$, the time variable of its world line. Suppose that we want now to set the clock at point $y$. We first place a mirror on this clock and then emit a light signal which propagates with the speed of light according to assumption 2' from our reference point at time $t_0$ and measure the time $t_1$ when it arrives back from $y$. The clock at $y$ should show the time $(t_1 - t_0)/2$ when the light has just reached.

I'm very rusty on all this, but I don't understand how such a procedure could work as stated. Both time measurements occur at $x=0$ and the information would need to be transported to $y$ which takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it takes an unknown amount of time to arrive, but the clock at $y$ already runs at the correct rate; you only need to set its zero point. So what you do is record the actual reading $t_2$ on the clock at $y$ when the light reflects off the mirror, and then whenever the value $(t_1-t_0)/2$ arrives at $y$, add $(t_1-t_0)/2-t_2$ to the current reading on the clock. The notes should have made it clearer that you need to record more than just $t_0$ and $t_1$.